# How can I add parameters to a Python Shell command?

Tags: python, node.js, django, command-line-arguments

I have a Django + Python application.
I have a python script that takes requirements as command line options.

The issue for me is that when I try to put in the command line arguments the script fails to execute. When I take out the command line arguments, it runs fine.
I need those command line arguments.

I am using node JS with Python Shell to execute the python script when the button is clicked in the django HTML front page.

Here is my code:

```
let {PythonShell} = require('python-shell')
var path = require("path")

function track_object() {
  //document.getElementById("detect").value = "One moment please ..."
  var python = require("python-shell")
  var path = require("path")

//let {PythonShell} = require('python-shell')

    var options = {
    scriptPath : path.join(__dirname, '/../engine/opencv-object-tracking/'),
    pythonPath : '/usr/bin/python'
    }

  **//let pyshell = new PythonShell("opencv_object_tracking.py --video dashcam_boston.mp4 --tracker csrt", options);
  let pyshell = new PythonShell("opencv_object_tracking.py", options);**

}
```

*Note: the two lines in bold are show the calling of the script with and without arguments*

Please let me know what is the correct way to pass command line arguments with Python Shell.

***** EDIT ******
here is my edit argparse:

```
# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-v", "--video", type=str,
    help="path to input video file")
ap.add_argument("-t", "--tracker", type=str, default="csrt",
    help="OpenCV object tracker type")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# extract the OpenCV version info
(major, minor) = cv2.__version__.split(".")[:2]

# if we are using OpenCV 3.2 OR BEFORE, we can use a special factory
# function to create our object tracker
if int(major) == 3 and int(minor) < 3:
    tracker = cv2.Tracker_create(args["tracker"].upper())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should add the arguments on your options variable. For example,

```
var options = {
    mode: 'text',
    scriptPath : path.join(__dirname, '/../engine/opencv-object-tracking/'),
    pythonPath : '/usr/bin/python',
    args: ['--video dashcam_boston.mp4 --tracker csrt']
    }
```

Also, you can add `pythonOptions: ['-u']` parameter if you require the outputs after the execution.

--Edit1--

It's strange but it's about the quote symbol. If you use `"` instead of `'`, it works very well. Here is the code below that works on my computer

```
 var options = {
   scriptPath : path.join(__dirname, './'),
   pythonPath : '/usr/bin/python',
   args: ["--video", "dashcam_boston.mp4","--tracker", "csrt"],
   mode: 'text'
 }

 let pyshell = new PythonShell("./opencv_object_tracking.py", options);
```

Comment: Gurses: That actually throws an error: Uncaught PythonShellError: usage: opencv_object_tracking.py [-h] [-v VIDEO] [-t TRACKER]
opencv_object_tracking.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --video dashcam_boston.mp4 --tracker csrt

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, the args should be element by element. Here the example `args: ['--video', 'dashcam_boston.mp4',' --tracker', 'csrt']`

Comment: i made a small change to the python script itself to make sure only the video is a parameter. WHen I then execute my application calling the python script -- nothing happens.

Comment: Is it possible to share your python argparse init?

Comment: I edited my answer with a %100 working solution :).

Comment: I had to add the full path to the video and it now works as I expect it to. Ani Gurses's answer is the solution